# Rigacar wheels not rotating when animated on a path

Tags: animation

So basically, for some reason, the car rig just doesn't rotate the wheels when keyframed on a path. I haven't had this problem occur for me up until now. The wheels still rotate when moved with the bone selected, just not on a path.

[image]

Comment: Welp I found my answer. It turns out, I was using the object constraint instead of the bone constraint